# PHP Function Kilomega echo result

Tags: php, mysql

```
function kilomega( $val ) {
if( $val < 1000 ) return $val;
$val = (int)($val/1000);
if( $val < 1000 ) return "${val}k";
$val = (int)($val/1000);
return "${val}m";
}
```

I want to set that function into my result data in table :

```
echo "<td class='td'>kilomega($sum_qty9)</td>";
```

But facing problem, the result of the echo to be :

kilomega(5000) should be 5k

Any advice ?

Comment: You have two conditions that are identical so this one will never be reached `if( $val < 1000 ) return "${val}k";` because you're returning earlier.

Comment: How about `echo "<td class='td'>", kilomega($sum_qty9), "</td>"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function calls are not interpolated in a string so

```
echo "<td class='td'>kilomega($sum_qty9)</td>";
```

should change to

```
echo "<td class='td'>",kilomega($sum_qty9),"</td>";
```